# Adjust the opacity of the lines in a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

Here is what I am trying to plot:

```
randomWalk := NestList[# + RandomReal[{-1, 1}] &, 0, 1000];
Show[Table[ListPlot[randomWalk, Joined -> True], {100}], PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Which gives:

[image]

What I'd like to do is give the lines a bit of transparency so that it is clearer to see the density of the plot at various areas; i.e. the darker the area, the more overlapping lines there are at that point. Since this is a `ListPlot` though, how can you change the properties - i.e. opacity - of the lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Putting the table inside `ListPlot` and setting the `Opacity` as part of the `PlotStyle`:

```
ListPlot[
  Table[randomWalk, {100}], 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Blue, Opacity[0.25]], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: `PlotStyle -> Opacity[1/5, Black]` also works.

Comment: @Alexy - This one will run and run ;)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Ymareth and Oska